# my asynchronous function returning Promise { <pending> } instead of a value?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

log  Promise {  } instead of a value?

getdata function log :  {
'start-time': '2021-11-29 08:54:00',
'end-time': '2021-11-29 10:54:00',
'entity-type': 'lun',
metric: 'throughput'
}

```
 async function getdata(params) {
  const data = await params
  console.log("<<<<<<", data);
  return data;
}

io.on("connection", async (data) => {
  data.on("token", (token) => {
    console.log(">>", token);
    // tokenData(tokenid)
  });
  data.on("params", async (params) => {
    let formData = await params
    getdata(formData)
    // console.log("<<<", params);
  })
})

console.log("PPPP", getdata() ); : Promise { <pending> }
```

Comment: Because `console.log(someAsync())` is not awaiting the `someAsync()`

Comment: I can explain with more examples, I do not understand

Comment: I want to store the retrun essence function in one place and use it

Comment: When you invoke the `getdata(formData)`, dont it be `await getdata(formData)`?

Comment: when you do `console.log("PPPP", getdata());` then `getdata()` returns a Promise (because it's `async`). But you are not awaiting this Promise, but just outputting the result of `getdata()` (which -- again -- is a promise). If you want to log out the `data` you have to do `console.log("PPPP", await getdata())` but that of course only works, if you are calling that `console.log` inside an async function.